# AdaBoosting with several different base estimators at once

Tags: python, scikit-learn, adaboost

I know you can AdaBoost with multiple instances of a single model (e.g., 600 Decision Trees, Bayesian Ridges, or Linear Models).  Is it possible to AdaBoost with a gauntlet of models at the same time, and how?

```
AdaBoost([DecisionTree, BayesianRidge, LinearRegressor, ...])
```

Each standalone model has its pros and cons, and I was wondering if it was possible to mash them all together under an umbrella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AdaBoost is decoupled from the weak classifier's implementation: Yes, you can. These architectures are called *hybrid ensembles*. However, it's not always needed as AdaBoost only requires the weak classifiers to be slightly better than random. Thus, it's often enough to have a homogenous ensemble of classifiers. In the end you'll have to test it for your own scenario if it gives you a performance boost.

Comment: Can you provide a simple code implementation?  I can't seem to find anything for doing this.

Comment: In scikit? I'm not sure if it's possible since it's using a `base_parameter`. You might have to modify it, write it yourself or find a different library.